# Function that runs on a standalone script does not WORK on another script Javascript, node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to run a .bat file using `Javascript` on **node.js**.

This is the code that I have so far:

```
function runBat(){
    var exec = require('child_process').execSync;
    var result = exec('C:\\Temp\\tasks\\acis\\runme.bat');
    console.log('result: ' + result);
    };

    runBat();
```

This function runs without problem when I store it in a seperate script.

But when I run with original script, which contains the code for the creation of the bat file, the bat file does not run.

**How should I make it run with other code?**

I'm trying not to use any call backs, because they tend to create other problems along the way

Sorry, couldn't mention you guys. I'm trying not to use asynchronous functions as well

Comment: you have mentioned more files or code that i can see/help you with, please make sure this is a complete answer so we can help you out

Comment: What is the error that you are getting..?

Comment: can you show us the code that create the batch file ?

Comment: @venkat7668 - It is not an error. It just prints out the the word 'result:'. The batch file is supposed to produce some xml files, which does not happen in this case

Comment: @ Mauricio, what I meant was more code. The code that creates the batch file

Answer (score 0):

This should work..?

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    ls    = spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c', 'C:\\Temp\\tasks\\acis\\runme.bat']);

ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

ls.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});

ls.on('exit', function (code) {
console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. All I have to do was just put a delay before calling the function

```
setTimeout(runBat, 3000);
```

Thanks guys, for all your help